# How to access the current redux store while in an interval in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In a project i am currently working on i have an interval that is called every three seconds to pool the server to see what the status of some processes on the server.

I am however having an issue. I need to look into the current state to get an id from the redux store that is placed there after the file has been uploaded but i have noticed that you can only access the state that existed when the interval was created.

does anyone have an idea of how i can access the current state from an interval with react and redux?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a React component that has access to state and can use redux actions during an interval to start the status queries. Just start and stop the interval during lifecycle methods.

You could also use redux-sagas (if you have experience with it) to create a saga similar to following:

```
while (true) {
  const state = yield select(); // Get state
  // Create status query event or do query here
  yield delay(3 * 1000); // Sleep
}
```